# BlueprintJS RadioGroup/Radio issue with defaultChecked/checked prop

Tags: blueprintjs

I'm trying to setup a `RadioGroup` component that has the `Radio` component with the 'Data' label initially checked. But when I use the following code:

```
<RadioGroup
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.store.setDataFilterSelection(e.target.value)
  }}
  >
  <Radio label='Data'
    defaultChecked
    value='1'
    className='radio-selectors' />
  <Radio label='Description'
    value='2'
    className='radio-selectors' />
  <Radio label='Data Source'
    value='3'
    className='radio-selectors' />
</RadioGroup>
```

I get the following warning in my console.

> Blueprint.Radio contains an input of type radio with both checked and
>   defaultChecked props. Input elements must be either controlled or
>   uncontrolled (specify either the checked prop, or the defaultChecked
>   prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled
>   input element and remove one of these props. More info:
>   react-controlled-components

I've tried a couple of variations and can't seem to get it right, basically I want to be able to monitor a change in the Radio buttons, but I can't tie them into state as they've done in the example here: http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.forms.radio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultChecked` is only supported in uncontrolled usage (this is a core React concept, not a Blueprint thing), whereas `checked` is only supported in controlled usage--this is what the React error is telling you.

But if you're using `RadioGroup` then all the `Radio` children are forced into controlled mode and all state should go through `RadioGroup`. However `RadioGroup` does not currently support a `defaultValue` prop so this is not actually possible. I'd call this a bug in Blueprint, so good find!

Please [file an issue](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/new) on the repo and we'll look into implementing this (or even better, submit a PR with the fix!)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this, obviously its a specific case for me not wanting to use state here. I think I could refactor and use state to set default value, but will review my case again and determine if I think it's worthy of a PR or if I'm just being stupid not using state.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and I used useState and set the value which we want to be default while declaring the state like

`const [radio, setRadio] = useState('defaultValue');`.

Since we cant use defaultChecked I used the above method to get the option to be default checked.